# Define function in macros (in C)

Tags: c, macros

I need to #define a macros as a function. For example:

```
#define REGISTER 0x80000000
...
writel(addr, nic->regs + REGISTER); // arguments are address and register
```

I defined it like that:

```
#define WRITEL(addr, nic->reg + reg) ((writel(addr, nic->regs + (reg))))
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a paticular reason to do it as a macro, not the normal function with all the benefits (type checking ...... etc etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macro arguments are a bit like normal function arguments. On the left side you just need a name that is used on the right

```
 #define WRITEL(ADDR, REG) (writel(ADDR, nic->regs + (REG)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Never did these things. I think I got the principle. I really appreciate your help

Comment: But is it necessary to cover the function with () ?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. it is not.

Comment: Sorry @tilz0R is correct. It was muscle memory. Any other expression than a single bare function call would require the parentheses.

Comment: @JeremyP I think it is good practice to put them. Maybe someday `writel` will be a new macro and then who knows what can happen.

Comment: @tilz0R That's a good point. Keeping the parentheses is defensive.